# UIVisualEffectView blur image

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, image-processing, blur

I use UIVisualEffectView to blur my imageview. Than I use this code to convert it to image and save to image library.

```
 UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(imageContainerView.bounds.size, true, 1)
 imageContainerView.drawHierarchy(in: imageContainerView.bounds, afterScreenUpdates: true)
 let newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()!
 UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
```

imageContainerView is a view which contains imageview and UIVisualEffectView.

Before I convert imageContainerView to image I increase it's size to 2000x2000 so I will get high quality image, If I don't do this all images inside imageContainerView becomes pixelated.

The problem is that after converting imageContainerView to image the blurred image becomes almost not blurred because I increased size of container view.

Can you suggest a solution for this problem?
I just want to get a blurred image so if you know other way to blur image using slider (the blur code should work fast so the UI will not freeze) please tell me.

Comment: Have you tried *not* resizing the `imageContainerView` and setting the `scale` argument of  `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions` to `0` (which will automatically match the scale factor of the device you're using)?

`UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(imageContainerView.bounds.size, true, 0)`

Comment: Can you explain what's the difference. Let's say the scale factor of the device is 2 so it will double the size of containerView. What's the difference if I do it manually ?

Answer (score 0):

> I just want to get a blurred image

Ok you can implement some of your blur filter effects, like this one, and slider to it.

```
var context = CIContext(options: nil)

func blur() {

    let blurFilter = CIFilter(name: "CIGaussianBlur") 
    let beginImage = CIImage(image: YOURIMAGE!)
    blurFilter!.setValue(beginImage, forKey: kCIInputImageKey)
    blurFilter!.setValue(8, forKey: kCIInputRadiusKey)

    let cropFilter = CIFilter(name: "CICrop")
    cropFilter!.setValue(blurFilter!.outputImage, forKey: kCIInputImageKey)
    cropFilter!.setValue(CIVector(cgRect: beginImage!.extent), forKey: "inputRectangle")

    let output = cropFilter!.outputImage 
    let cgImg = context.createCGImage(output!, from: output!.extent)
    let processedImage = UIImage(cgImage: cg cgImg mg!)
    bg.image = processedImage
}
```

Or there are multiple libraries on GitHub like this one eg.: https://github.com/FlexMonkey/Blurable

Comment: Your solution is much slow comparing to just changing alpha of visual effect view